# How do I exclude commas from my regex search?

Tags: regex

I am trying to find the last 7 digits of all these numbers and remove them. The problem is that my regex pattern matches things like commas and brackets

Example:

`{ "bbox": [-75, 46.04626545582789, -73.68596912341107, 46.953529202292515], "name": "18T-WS" },`

My Regex:

`(\d{7})(\D)`

This is mostly good but the regex is matching the commas. How do I exclude them? I am only searching for the last 7 digits after the decimal

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/telA7K/4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may intend use a positive lookahead:

```
\d{7}(?=\D)
```

This would match any sequence of 7 digits which are immediately followed by a non digit.

### Demo

Side note: It appears that the content you are searching is actually JSON.  If so, then you should be using a JSON parser here for at least part of the work.  Maybe you would use a regex to trim some of the values, but a parser is what should be getting you there.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. Never used a JSON parser. Very new to all of this. Is there one that you would recommend?

Comment: Well I don't even know what language you are using.  JavaScript itself basically is a JSON parser, Python, Java, and C# have very good JSON libraries available.

Comment: JavaScript.  On second though I could have just looped over it and used toFixed()... I think I need some sleep